# multipart/form-data returns empty object | Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, enctype

Form with POST method and enctype="multipart/form-data" returns empty object in Nodejs Express.

In `app.js` I have used:

```
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
```

While using only **POST** **type** and **action** in the `<form>` tag

**req.body** gives output in json smoothly and have no issues.

But using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in express **req.body** returns `{ }` - empty object

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `urlencoded` middleware only handles the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type and `json` handles the `application/json` content type. If you specifically need to use `multipart/form-data` (e.g. if you need to handle file uploads), you'll need a package for that, since as of writing, express doesn't come with a multipart parser out of the box. Common packages used to handle multipart are [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) and [`formidable`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable#readme).

Alternatively, if you don't need to upload files or other binary content, just remove the `enctype` attribute as `<form>` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Hey...Thanks for the idea. Actually, I need both the text inputs and file uploads in the same form... That's why I'm facing the issue. When removing the ```enctype``` it gives me the result. But the problem is while I need both in the same form. And I used  ```multer``` too

Comment: Multer should work, can you show how you tried using multer? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67082969/edit) your post to add details.

Answer (score 0):

incase your using multer, its possible that your calling the upload method last, please call the upload that checks for image and then the other data from the form can later be submitted

i will give an example of my route

```
router.post('/add-product',productController.isUserAllowed,upload.single('avatar'), productController.add_product);
```

so initally i was calling `productController.add_product` before`upload.single('avatar')`, and it didnt work, till i started with the upload that checked the image , then the add_product